# polite answers and questions as to failure to meet deadlines

Tags: phrase-request

Suggest please how to ask a colleague at work (or a contractor) about progress of his work if you suspect that he or she is "slow" in doing work. In particular, you want to know if he or she is going to miss deadlines. Or you have noticed that he or she is messing about at the workplace.

I am curious about polite answers to such a question too.

Examples:

> A: How are you making out with the deadline (unidiomatic in my opinion)?
>
> A: Do you think you will do it in time? (colloquial, imho)
>
> B: I have to admit I am coming short of the (established) deadline. Sorry. or
>
> B: I am doing my best but I will come short of completing work on time.
>
> B: I feel I won't do it at the appointed time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom is that you **make the deadline**. Making *out* with it means something else completely!

> Do you think you can make the deadline?
>   I don't think I can make the deadline, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I heard it before but I didn't remember how exactly this phrase sounds. I think, I meant another phrasal verb 'get along with'. How are you getting along with your work/the deadline. Is it possible to say in this situation?

Comment: @Humbulani: you can get along with people, you can ask how the work is _coming along_. Asking how the deadline is coming along means that you have no deadline yet, and you are asking someone how far they are in the process of setting it.

Comment: I am not sure whether the examples are always correct in the Macmillan dictionary. But I found the following definition for 'get along with':to manage to continue doing something or make progress in a situation

Comment: get along with: How are you getting along with your schoolwork? http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-along